# Horizontal collection view in table view using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I am desperately trying to put a horizontal scrolling collection view into a table view cell using autolayout, but the collection view and therefore the tableview cell won't layout as intended, so they end up being zero in height. I have already looked at every post I could find here on SO regarding this topic, but none of them helped me resolve the problem.

The general structure looks like this:

> TableView
>
> > Table View Cell
> >
> > > Collection View
> > >
> > > > | Collection View Cell | Collection View Cell | ...
> >
> > Table View Cell
> >
> > > Collection View
> > >
> > > > | Collection View Cell | Collection View Cell | ...

I have set the TableView auto resizing properties

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
```

as well as the collection view flow layout properties:

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
```

TableViewCell layout:

```
contentView.layout("H:|[a]|", views: collectionView)
contentView.layout("V:|[a]|", views: collectionView)
```

CollectionViewCell layout:

```
contentView.layout("H:|[a]|", views: imageView)
contentView.layout("H:|[a]|", views: titleLabel)
contentView.layout("H:|[a]|", views: subtitleLabel)
contentView.layout("V:|[a]-(4)-[b][c]|", views: imageView, titleLabel, subtitleLabel)
```

I have already tried to set the collection view's height manually, but its contentSize is always zero, maybe because it has no space to potentially render its cells.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
}
```

I think I need to tell the collection view to layout anywhere in my code, and also give it enough space, but my attempts ended up in tons of auto layout errors at runtime. So maybe someone can help me with this one, I really don't want to hardcode the heights.

Thank you in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

you may use "**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**", it tells collection view the size of every cell, then add auto layout constrains for cell's subview items.

apply your collection view to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, and set
collection view's dataSource and delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height)
    }
```

Comment: The thing is, the cells don't have a fixed size, they should autolayout themselves.

Comment: what's about add your subViews in a container view, set this view sizeToFit, use this container's frame to set cell's size dynamically